# Powershell Import-Csv New-AdUser skip if user exists

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I have a fully functional script to import and create AD Users, but I would like to skip from attempting to create Users that are already in AD.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$CsvPath = "C:\Shares\Users.csv"
$CsvTest = Test-Path $CsvPath

Import-Csv $CsvPath | ForEach-Object {
Get-AdUser $_.sAMAccountName
}

Import-Csv $CsvPath | ForEach-Object {  
New-ADUser -Name $_.Name -UserPrincipalName $_.userPrincipalName -SamAccountName $_.sAMAccountName -DisplayName $_.DisplayName -GivenName $_.GivenName -Surname $_.Surname -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $_.Password  -AsPlainText -force)  -Enabled $true -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true

{

Catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser] 

}
    $_."sAMAccountName";  "already exists"
    }
```

Comment: You do not test the code you write here. You just expect somebody writes it for you ?

Comment: No need for the smart remarks. I was just asking for help, what is the point of this website otherwise.

Comment: The point is to help people who met real problems, not people who wants their job done by other people for free. In your case read the input file once, test for the existence of the user, and if it does not exists create it. It looks like B+A -> BA. If you meet an error that you can't explain using the WEB, then SO is here.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this without relying on exceptions would be better:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$csvPath = "C:\Shares\Users.csv"

if (Test-Path $csvPath)
{
    $newUsers = Import-Csv $csvPath
    $existingUsers = Get-ADGroupMember "Domain Users"

    foreach ($newUser in $newUsers)
    {
        if (($existingUsers | Where-Object { $_.sAMAccountName -eq $newUser.sAMAccountName }) -eq $null)
        {
            $user = New-ADUser -Name $newUser.Name -UserPrincipalName $newUser.userPrincipalName -SamAccountName $newUser.sAMAccountName -DisplayName $newUser.DisplayName -GivenName $newUser.GivenName -Surname $newUser.Surname -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $newUser.Password -AsPlainText -Force) -Enabled $true -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
        }
    }
}
```

Personally I prefer to use the Quest AD Module for Powershell as it avoids exceptions by returning $null when an object doesn't exist.